# Creating a query for mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

defined variables :

```
    let min_cost = '';
    let status   = '';
    let min_rent = '';
    let filter = {};
```

I have a structure below `$and: []` and it has three objects as defined below, Here I am trying to insert those three objects one by one only if the payload contains their values. For Ex.: if `min_cost !== ''`, then the first object should be pushed into `$and : []` and same with the status and `min_rent`, Then finally inserting `$and : []` into filter object.

```
{
       $and: [
            {
                $and: [
                    { "data.label": "Total Cost" },
                    {
                        "data.value": {
                            "$gte": min_cost
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                $and: [
                    { "data.label": "Possession Status" },
                    { "data.value": status }
                ],

            },
            {
                $and: [
                    { "data.label": "Estimated Monthly Rent" },
                    {
                        "data.value": {
                            "$gte": min_rent
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },

        ]
}
```

final output :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  "$match": filter
}
])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if condition and push `$and` object to filter array and after all conditions put `$and` with `filter` array in `$match` stage.

```
let min_cost = '';
let status   = '';
let min_rent = '';
let filter = [];

if (min_cost) {
    filter.push({
        $and: [
            { "data.label": "Total Cost" },
            { "data.value": { "$gte": min_cost } }
        ]
    });
}

if (status) {
    filter.push({
        $and: [
            { "data.label": "Possession Status" },
            { "data.value": status }
        ]
    });
}

if (min_rent) {
    filter.push({
        $and: [
            { "data.label": "Estimated Monthly Rent" },
            { "data.value": { "$gte": min_rent } }
        ]
    });
}

db.collection.aggregate([
    {  "$match": filter.length ? { $and: filter } : {} }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , In "$match" stage i don't want to add key value pair directly , as you have put $and as a key for filter , what if filter array is empty , then what can be another way to handle that . Also  i am beginner and learning mongodb  .

Comment: update : I got the solution , i also defined one object as obj and created "$and" as a key and added filter array as its value to it , and then i passed the object in $match stage as { "$match" : obj } , Thanks @turivishal

Comment: great, i have added a condition in the query if it will help you.

Comment: Hi , I have one question ,In match stage if i use { "$gte": min_cost , "$lte": max_cost }, will it filter Total cost between min_cost and max_cost , because when i am trying use $gte and $lte is is not giving proper output . Link for playground : 
 https://mongoplayground.net/p/EXHSY6UmGca

Comment: use `$elemMatch` and `$all` operator, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jMW6aROgQ1w)